# Play Framework Scala Hello-World fail on Ubuntu 20

Tags: scala, playframework

The basic Play Framework sample (play-scala-hello-world-tutorial) fails on Ubuntu 20 with OpenAdopt JDK but works fine on Macos. Is there something arry with my Linux setup?

Per https://www.playframework.com/getting-started) I...

```
> git clone https://github.com/playframework/play-samples.git
> cd play-samples/play-scala-hello-world-tutorial
> sbt run  
    [info] welcome to sbt 1.4.3 (AdoptOpenJDK Java 16)
    [info] loading global plugins from /home/gp/.sbt/1.0/plugins
    [info] loading settings for project play-scala-hello-world-tutorial-build from plugins.sbt,scaffold.sbt ...
    [info] loading project definition from /home/.../play-samples/play-scala-hello-world-tutorial/project
    [warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies; run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings.
    [info] loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
    [info] set current project to play-scala-hello-world-tutorial (in build file:/home/.../play-samples/play-scala-hello-world-tutorial/)

--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Listening for HTTP on /[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0]:9000

(Server started, use Enter to stop and go back to the console...)
```

curl localhost:9000

results in this:

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.reload(DevServerStart.scala:254)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.get(DevServerStart.scala:148)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.handleRequest(AkkaHttpServer.scala:302)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.$anonfun$createServerBinding$1(AkkaHttpServer.scala:224)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.MapAsync$$anon$30.onPush(Ops.scala:1297)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:541)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processEvent(GraphInterpreter.scala:495)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:390)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:625)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:502)
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2051)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3951)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3974)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4958)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4964)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:49)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:155)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:592)
    at com.google.inject.internal.AbstractBindingProcessor$Processor.initializeBinding(AbstractBindingProcessor.java:173)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:79)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:119)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:294)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:258)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:207)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.create(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:49)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:156)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:94)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DuplicatesPredicate.evaluate(DuplicatesPredicate.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$CollectionUtils.filter(CollectionUtils.java:52)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter.<init>(FastClassEmitter.java:69)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.generateClass(FastClass.java:77)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:332)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:96)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:94)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
Caused by: com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException-->Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @5f574e3d
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:464)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:339)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:96)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:94)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:119)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:294)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @5f574e3d
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1.run(ReflectUtils.java:61)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils.<clinit>(ReflectUtils.java:52)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter.<init>(FastClassEmitter.java:67)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.generateClass(FastClass.java:77)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)


>java -version  
openjdk version "16" 2021-03-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 16+36)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 16+36, mixed mode, sharing)
    
> sbt sbtVersion
[info] welcome to sbt 1.3.13 (AdoptOpenJDK Java 16)
[info] loading global plugins from /home/../.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] loading settings for project play-scala-hello-world-tutorial-build from scaffold.sbt,plugins.sbt ...
[info] loading project definition from /home/.../play-samples/play-scala-hello-world-tutorial/project
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies; run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings.
[info] loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
[info] set current project to play-scala-hello-world-tutorial (in build file:/home/.../play-samples/play-scala-hello-world-tutorial/)
[info] 1.3.13
```

project/build.properties:

```
# sbt.version=1.3.13
sbt.version=1.4.3
```

Comment: Try using java 8 or java 11 instead of java 16, play may not be fully compatible with java 16 yet. You can find something useful [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-on-ubuntu-18-04) about installing different versions

Comment: Could be. I'm using the exact same AdoptOpenJDK version 16 on mac though and Play's happy. I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having the same issue with *JDK-11*

Trying with Java8 solved the issue.

Comment: Do you now why jdk 11 is not allowed? [Play Requirements](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/Requirements) is Java SE 1.8 **or higher**

Comment: No, I don’t. But in fact, I tried again with `JDK-11` and it’s working. (I believe that it was a problem with cache or something similar)

From scratch, what I did:
- Clone the repo -> `Play samples`
- Check my Java version (`JDK-11`). Also, check if my `JAVA_HOME` was set to `JDK-11` as well and, because I’m on iOS and using jenv, sometimes it doesn’t set the `JAVA_HOME` properly. I've checked also that the project on IntelliJ was using `JDK-11`
- `sbt clean`
- `sbt run` and hit `http://localhost:9000`

Comment: btw, for JDK-17, refer to https://discuss.lightbend.com/t/play-sample-on-windows-java-lang-illegalstateexception-unable-to-load-cache-item/8663/2.

Answer (score 5):

Play 2.8.16 is dependent on google Guice version **4.2.3**, which only support jdk 14, to make this run with java 17, you need to add the following code snippet into your **build.sbt**

```
dependencyOverrides ++= Seq(
  "com.google.inject" % "guice" % "5.1.0",
  "com.google.inject.extensions" % "guice-assistedinject" % "5.1.0")
```

Here are few links you can have a look :-

1. https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Guice423
2. https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Guice510
3. https://github.com/playframework/playframework/releases/2.8.15

Adding the above snippet code would make it able to run with 17.

Answer (score 1):

For me is the opposite of [@ProofJS's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68192874/3025856). On Windows 10,
JDK8 would not work (it would not compile - `sbt compile`). **JDK 11 worked without problems**. JDK 17 did compile, but would not run - `sbt run`.

```
welcome to sbt 1.3.13 (Oracle Corporation Java 11.0.12)
```

In IntelliJ, in the context menu for the project (right click) -> Open Module Settings -> Project -> SDK 11.0.12.

build.properties (file):

```
sbt.version=1.3.13
```

plugins.sbt (file):

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.8.11")
```

build.sbt (file):

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
  .settings(
    name := """play-scala-forms-example""",
    version := "2.8.x",
    scalaVersion := "2.13.7",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      guice,
      "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "5.1.0" % Test,
    ),
    scalacOptions ++= Seq(
      "-feature",
      "-deprecation",
      "-Xfatal-warnings"
    )
  )
```

System Env: JAVA_HOME & Path set to JDK-11/bin

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30645042)

Comment: I'm not as convinced as @sinanspd that this _isn't_ an answer, but it's certainly not _clear_. Mehdi, are you saying that this solved your problem? If so, you should make this clear. Or are you saying you ran into a related problem? If the latter, you should create a new question, as sinanspd suggests.

Comment: To jeremy it clearly state that for jdk11 it worked without problem! with version of sbt and scala mentioned in the post. I am not sure what it is not clear